# Python: Printing value after .upper

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print a string in all uppercase letters. When I run the print command it prints the type of x and the location.

Why does it print the operation instead of the result?

```
x = 'bacon'
x = x.upper
print x

>>> 
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x02A95F60>
```

Comment: This is a pretty legit question. Not sure why you got the downvote.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's something that could have been solved with [30 seconds of google](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)... that's why

Comment: @Aaron. As someone that is very familiar with Python, this is true, but grasping the idea that a function is just an attribute of a thing is not intuitive at all in the beginning. I would have found it difficult to come up with a good set of keywords to search for as a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in Python is an object, including functions and methods. `x.upper` is the `upper` attribute of `x`, which happens to be a function object. `x.upper()` is the result of trying to call that attribute as a function, so you are trying to do

```
print x.upper()
```

As an aside, you can try to call any object in Python, not just functions. It will not always work, but the syntax is legitimate. You can do

```
x = 5
x()
```

or even

```
5()
```

but of course you will get an error (the exact same one in both cases). However, you can actually call objects as functions as long as they define a `__call__` method (as normal functions do). Your example can actually be rewritten as

```
print x.upper.__call__()
```

Answer (score 4):

`upper` (and all other methods) is something like "function ready to use", that way you can do:

```
x = 'bacon'
x = x.upper
print x()
```

But the most common to see, and the way I think you want is:

```
x = 'bacon'
x = x.upper()
print x
```

"Ridiculous" example using [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk):

```
upper_case = lambda x: x.upper()
print(upper_case) # <function <lambda> at 0x7f2558a21938>
print(upper_case('bacon')) # BACON
```

Comment: Add in an explanation please!

Comment: This worked, thank you for the suggestion. What is the significance of x.upper() vs x.upper?

Comment: you must add parenthesis to call a function. what you did was copy the upper method of x to a variable named x (overwriting it's previous value)

Comment: StmWtr, when you do upper without the parens, it it simply a reference to the method. Adding them actually executes it.

Comment: @StmWtr imagine functions in pythons like a small machine. When you call `.upper` you are saying "Hey! Get that machine for me". But when you call `.upper()` you are saying "Hey! Use that machine for me".